# Communicating between apps, startService() or sendBroadcast()

Tags: android

I have two applications,  App A & App B.

 App A need to send some data(or communicate to do something) to App B.


What is the best way to do this.
App B can have a broadcast listener to receive the broadcast from App A.
Or I can export a service from App A, so that App B can call startService()

From my experience, broadcast is received very slow, but when calling startService App A is started fast.

Is there is any issues with startService() that App A need to be concerned about with all the background service limitations from Android O.

Comment: Eventually service is need to be started from App A, when App B asks to do something.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is any issues with startService() that App A need to be concerned about with all the background service limitations from Android O.

App A should offer an exported `Service` which other components can bind to. Then if App B is in the foreground and has started the `Service` as a [bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services), the `Service` (and with it all of App A) will be considered to be in the foreground as well.

See also the paragraph "Background Service Limitations" in [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) for Oreo (App B would be "another foreground app")